# Sample size needed for test of binomial using Fishers exact test

Tags: hypothesis-testing, fishers-exact-test

I am running two different advertisements served up randomly.  I monitor how many people respond to each advertisement.  I am trying to determine if one ad is better than the other.  If I run a Fisher's significance test on the results I can find if the null hypothesis can be rejected at any point in time.

I think it can be confidently said that the two ads will have different response rates no matter how small the difference, but how can I test that the results are no more than 5% different in terms of response rate?

Comment: Are you talking about something like an equivalence test, or are you looking more for the information provided by confidence intervals?